# Is it dbase is support on Codeigniter 3?

Tags: codeigniter, dbase

In my office, there are an old app that store the database on dbf. Is it CI3 support to dbase with extension *dbf ?? 
I have try :  http://www.phpclasses.org/package/2673-PHP-Access-dbf-foxpro-files-without-PHP-ext-.html.

Should be a helper or library or database in config ?

For the solution, thanks ...

Answer (score 0):

Codeigniter only supports MySQL (4.1+), MySQLi, MS SQL, Postgres, Oracle, SQLite, and ODBC.

Yes you can use this for migration and convert all dbf db entries into Codeigniter supported DBs .You will get more support for those db like mysql

Answer (score 0):

Probably there is no good solution for your problem. We had the same issue here, and there was no reasonable solution. Dbf files are ok for Isam access, but you probably cannot access index (.cdx) files so anything you try to do will be condemned by the low speed of access.
May be you may try Advantage Database Server, a propietary data server that uses dbf as one of their file formats. It has a library for PHP, so may be you want to give it a try.

In our case, we wrote a cron scripts that dumps the dbf contents into MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use ODBC probably by way of the Microsoft dBASE files Driver.

First you will have to configure an ODBC Data Source. How to do that is another question so I won't explain that part. Stackoverflow will likely have many examples of what is needed.

Use the ODBC Data Source to configure your CI database. It will be *something* along these lines...

```
$db['default'] = array(
     ...
    'hostname' => 'Driver={Microsoft dBASE Driver (*.dbf)};DriverID=277;DBQ=\path\to\my.dbf', // or try only the DNS name
    'username' => 'dbusername',
    'password' => 'dbpassword',
    'database' => '\path\to\my.dbf', //or try same string as 'hostname'
    'dbdriver' => 'odbc',
     ...
);
```

The performance - once you get it to work - will be awful and you will probably be much happier migrating the data to a different database system.